# Good user/group management in node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Need to implement user/group management in node.js. Any good frameworks out there?  Looked a little into passport.js, which seems to have authentication down down. Just not sure user/group stuff is built in. I can build my own users/groups and do auth with passport.js. Just wondering if there is something out there that I don't know about. Thanks!